# Enhanced Video Renderer(EVR) in Filtergraph

Tags: c#, .net, directshow

Thi is my filtergraph. when I run the graph, I don't see any video window. But, If I replace the EVR with some other rederer (VMR7, VMR9, etc.) I get the video window. Kindly Help.
[image]

Are there some changes to filtergraph  needs to be done? 
Moreover, I can't find any AVI Decoder, where can I find? Any recommended codec pack? for Windows 7...

Comment: Do you have video if you build the same graph in GraphEdit? In your app? EVRs require specific initialization, I am not sure if this app does it.

Comment: Hi Roman, I just figured out the problem. There was a connection problem, which kept me worried... Thanks!